# Does Allah allow ant keeping?

Tags: animals

So I have seen some YouTube **channels** keeping ants, Does Islam allow that? Please answer and it will help me.

Comment: Why wouldn’t He? As long as you’re not intentionally killing/hurting them.

Answer (score 0):

As a rule, anything that is not mentioned to be forbidden in the Quran or in qualfied hadith is judged halal. As nothing is ever mentioned about cultivation of ants and no restrictions on caring or cultivating animals in an appropriate place are known, there is nothing opposed to it as long as you are respecting given rules.

Comment: thank you for giving the answer